# dynamically add files to the public folder and getting the refreshed results in meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm playing around with the idea of using Meteor as a backend for creating a static html generator (with an admin UI).

I want that, when triggered, a new file will be created on the public folder and instantly reviewed by the author on an iframe embed in the html.

The file gets created but two side effects happen:

1. The server is restarted.
2. The file is cached - so the user can't see that the change took place.

Any ideas?

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {

  Template.hello.events = {
    'click input' : function () {
      Meteor.call('makeFile', 'filename.html', function(error, result){
        alert(result);
      });
     //window.location = '/filename.txt';

      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  };
}

if (Meteor.is_server) {
   var fs = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('fs');
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

  });
  Meteor.methods({
    'makeFile': function(fileName) {
      /*
      fs.unlink("public/"+fileName, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('successfully deleted ');
      });
  */
      fs.writeFile("public/"+fileName, "<html><body><h1>test</h1></body></html>", function(err) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("The file was saved! "+ fileName);


        }
      });
      return fileName;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the meteor server restarts whenever you change any file in a meteor subdirectory.  So to prevent this don't write your files within the meteor app directory, make a created_files directory one level up or something.  This is a good idea anyway, to separate the generated files from the code that's generating them.

Easiest way to show the content in the admin interface is probably to write it to the database (as opposed to trying to watch for directory changes).  No sense re-inventing the wheel, since Meteor is designed to watch for db updates.

Create a collection (at the top, so it's on client & server):

```
GeneratedFiles = new Meteor.Collection("generated_files");
```

Then assign the file contents to a variable before writing them and in your `fs.writeFile` callback:

```
if(err) {
  console.log(err);
} else {
  GeneratedFiles.insert({name: fileName, contents: fileContents});
  console.log("The file was saved! "+ fileName);
}
```

And then auto-publish the file contents to template in the client code (not sure why you want to use an iframe, seems like a div would work fine.  But either way would probably work).

Hope that helps.  And good luck, I think meteor is a great framework for this kind of thing.  Most of the admin interfaces I use are still entirely synchronous and just annoying to work with.