# meteor stop watch for the public folder

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have created uplods folder inside the public folder.

This folder is contains all the uploaded Images of my system.

as soon as possible I upload a file it automatically refresh the browser.

I have kept upload~ and ~upload but once file upload inside that then it will reloads.

and I want to access it by localhost:3000 so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360674/dynamically-add-files-to-the-public-folder-and-getting-the-refreshed-results-in) solution will not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Meteor will always keep watching for file changes in development mode. You could run on production mode but then you'd need to refresh every time you change code...

You do not want to store your uploaded content in public.

Here's my answer about this topic on Meteor Forums:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/why-shouldnt-i-upload-files-in-the-public-directory/36899/3

> Using something else than your meteor application to
>   manage/store/serve your user files have many many benefits.
>
> If your app crash, the file server is still available (current uploads
>   will continue). If your file server crash, the application can still
>   run and be used. Meteor is not good at serving files, so serving
>   user's files will impact your application performance, and the file
>   service itself. Storing files in Meteor's public folder make them
>   available to the entire world, you might not want that. File handling
>   and Server applications do not require the same server specifications,
>   so you'll want to separate them later. EDIT:
>
> I realize that, while giving better insights on your other options I
>   did not answer your question at all.
>
> Why shouldn't you store user's files in public? As it was pointed out,
>   any file in public will be available to the world. The public folder
>   is bundled with your app, it is considered to be part of your source.
>   It is meant to store resources to be used by your app, such as your
>   logo, custom icons and fonts etc... Just like your database, the
>   user's files are dynamic data that should be separated from your code,
>   they are not required by your application to run. They are used to
>   store information collected by your application and very much act in
>   pair, but their content is normally not following your application in
>   the different environment like development, staging and production.
>   When you will rebundle your app after some changes, you'll have a new
>   public folder content your images and font files, but not all the
>   files uploaded by your users while you were working, so you will have
>   to make sure that you are not deleting those files. Even if your
>   uploaded files are to be seen by everyone, you'll certainly use a
>   database to keep track of the uploaded files, their upload date,
>   owner, size, tags, etc... That means that even if you keep those files
>   around in dev/staging/production you will also need the full
>   database... Merging the database changes when pushing to production
>   will be even harder than just checking in on a folder...

An easy solution would be to use Meteor just like you do, but store the files somewhere outside your source code. And use NGINX to serve those files. Here's a NGINX config I am using to do about just that... It proxies the correct requests to Meteor and all the ones starting with "image" in the URL are directly served from `/img/`

```
server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version

# this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

# HTTP

server {
    listen 80 default_server; # if this is not a default server, remove "default_server"
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html; # root is irrelevant
    index index.html index.htm; # this is also irrelevant

    server_name meteor.localhost; # the domain on which we want to host the application. Since we set "default_server" previously, nginx will answer all hosts anyway.
        access_log /etc/nginx/logs/app.access;
        error_log /etc/nginx/logs/app.error error;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP

         if ($uri != '/') {
            expires 30d;
        }
    }
        location /image/{
                alias /img/;
                expires -1;
        }
}
```

Note that this means you'll be accessing your application through port 80 instead of 3000, as NGINX will take care of proxying.

Comment: how can i access my files under img folder?
it will be by localhost:3000/img?

Comment: in the example configuration, localhost/image points directly to your /img folder. You can change it at the bottom of the config example to whatever you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for your support but i got solution in meteor itself so no need to use ngix

Comment: yw, just note that if you ever grow into production, you'll still want a better alternative than Meteor, as it can easily crash just because of a too big public folder.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me

I have put below piece of code in client startup

```
Meteor._reload.onMigrate(function() {
 return [false];
});
```

Thanks it's working fine as required